# gradle error in android studio: Could not create parent directory for lock file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

**Gradle Error** : Could not create parent directory for lock file.

**Could not create parent directory for lock file D:\PROGRAM FILES\ANDROID\jbr\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.5-bin\f1w0cc9nuo0eivz97x2xlu9sv\gradle-7.5-bin.zip.lck**

**While building or syncing my app, the Gradle shows this error.**

**Please help me with this error.**

Comment: Try reboot, delete that .lck file, and try again

Answer (score 10):

Make your Gradle User Home to be empty [image: Make your Gradle User Home to be empty]

Then restart Android Studio and sync. Gradle error will be gone.

Comment: Finally a correct answer, thanks! I wonder how that ended up as '/sdk' for me, this is a new installation.

Answer (score 1):

As it was [already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76145179/2647298) - make your "Gradle User Home" setting empty.

How to find the setting in Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1:

[image: Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1]